# Visual C++ doesn't recognize my function as a part of a class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm making a decent program that will take any date, and find the day before and after it. I have everything finished, except when I debugged it, I got around 13 errors! After reading the error statements, I figured that the function wasn't recognized as part of the class, but I have no idea why.

I feel like I understand what I'm doing, but there's something that's not right. If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know. Thank you!

I have three files:

Main File (Source.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "DateType.h"



using namespace std;
int main() {
    //Inputs
    int month, day, year;
    bool flag;
    DateType today, tomorrow, yesterday;
    do { //Registers input and checks if it can go through program
        cout << "Enter the current month (1-12): ";
        cin >> month;
        cout << "Enter the current year: ";
        cin >> year;
        cout << "Enter in today's date: ";
        cin >> day;
        today.SetDate(month, day, year);
        flag = today.valid_date();
    } while (!flag);

    //Equalizing all three objects
    tomorrow = today;
    yesterday = today;
    //Moving ford and back one day
    tomorrow.NextDay();
    yesterday.PreviousDay();

    //Output
    cout << "Given Date: " << today.print_Day() << endl;
    cout << "Next Date: " << tomorrow.print_Day() << endl;
    cout << "Previous Date: " << yesterday.print_Day() << endl;









    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Header File (DateType.h)

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

enum months { Jan=31, Feb = 28, March = 31, April = 30, May = 31, 
    June = 30, July = 31, August = 31, Sept = 30, Oct = 31, Nov = 30, Dec = 31, Feb_Leap = 29 };

class DateType {
private:
    int mo;
    int day;
    int yr;
    months DaysInMonth;
    void Day_Month_Assign(); //This function does the same thing as DaysinMonth() on the assignment sheet, using the enum
public:
    DateType(); //Constructor to set mo=0, day=0, yr=1000
    void SetDate(int, int, int); //Date is set according to the incoming parameter
    void NextDay(); //Date is increased by one to get NextDay
    void PreviousDay(); //Date is decreased by one day to get Previous Day
    string print_Day(); //Returns a string value
    bool valid_date(); //Checks if an input is a valid date
};
```

DateType.cpp File

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "DateType.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

DateType::DateType() {
    mo = 0;
    day = 0;
    yr = 1000;
}

void DateType::Day_Month_Assign() {
    switch (mo) {
    case 1: DaysInMonth = Jan;
    case 2: DaysInMonth = Feb;
    case 3: DaysInMonth = March;
    case 4: DaysInMonth = April;
    case 5: DaysInMonth = May;
    case 6: DaysInMonth = June;
    case 7: DaysInMonth = July;
    case 8: DaysInMonth = August;
    case 9: DaysInMonth = Sept;
    case 10: DaysInMonth = Oct;
    case 11: DaysInMonth = Nov;
    case 12: DaysInMonth = Dec;
    }
    if ((yr % 4 == 0 && yr % 100 != 0) ||
        (yr % 400 == 0))
        DaysInMonth = Feb_Leap;
}

void DateType::SetDate(int month, int days, int year) {
    mo = month;
    day = days;
    yr = year;
    Day_Month_Assign();
}

void DateType::NextDay() {
    day++;
    if (day > DaysInMonth) { //Raises month
        day = 1;
        mo++;
        Day_Month_Assign(); //Assigns new value to enum
    }
    if (mo > 12) {
        mo = 1;
        yr++;
        Day_Month_Assign();
    }
}

void DateType::PreviousDay() {
    day--;
    //Different order than the last one
    //I need to get the days in month from enum first 
    //That will be the new day value
    if (day == 0) {
        mo--;
        Day_Month_Assign();
        day = DaysInMonth;
    }
    if (mo == 0) {
        yr--;
        mo = 12;
        Day_Month_Assign();
        day = DaysInMonth;
    }
}

string DateType::print_Day() {
    string date;
    date = (to_string(mo) + "-" + to_string(day) + "-" + to_string(yr));
    return date;
}

bool DateType::valid_date() {
    bool flag;
    if (day <= DaysInMonth && day >= 1) { //Days in Month Check
        if (mo > 0 && mo <= 12) { //Month in Year Check
            flag = true;
            cout << "Valid Date, Accepted!\n";
        }
        else {
            flag = false;
            cout << "Invalid Month!\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        flag = false;
        cout << "Invalid Date!\n";
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Edit: The function in question is the `String DateType::print_Day()` function. Here are the errors:

Main File:

```
'print_Day' is not a member of 'DateType' (Called 3 Times), C2039
```

CPP File:

```
'print_Day' is not a member of 'DateType' (Line 73, C2039)

'mo': undeclared identifier (Line 75, C2065)

'day': undeclared identifier (Line 75, C2065)

'yr': undeclared identifier (Line 75, C2065)

declaration is incompatible with " DateType::print_Day()" (declared at line 21 of Header File) (Line 73, E0147)
```

Header File:

```
'print_Day': unknown override specifier (Line 21, C3646)

syntax error: '(' (Line 21, C2059)

unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (Line 21, C2238)
```

All three of the header file errors are thrown again later on in the error list. I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please add the error messages [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63836701/edit) also (best formatted as code). Without seeing these it's a bit hard to diagnose.

Comment: Which function? There are six. (Focus on the tirst message. A minor C++ problem can cause a whole cascade of pseudo-errors.)

Comment: At a guess it is print_Day.  string should be std::string.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't forget to `break` between `case` statements in a `switch` unless you want the `case` to fall through to and execute the next `case` as well (and you don't). Side note: the `switch` can be replaced with a look-up table.

Comment: This is as good a time as any to give up the “using namespace std;” habit.

Answer (score 4):

In DateType.h, string is not known because the string class belongs to std namespace.  To fix the error, change the definition of print_Day to

```
std::string print_Day()
```

Do not try to fix it by adding `using namespace std;` in the header - that will cause no end of problems further down the line.

Small note on programming style: in DateType.cpp, it would be better to include DateType.h before anything else.  That way, you will know that DateType.h has no dependencies and can be included in any cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t address the question, but don’t name a variable `flag`. Give variables names that tell you what they do. In this case, `date_is_valid`, although a bit long, is much clearer. But you don’t need it. Just make the loop test `while(!today.valid_date())`.